# How to GET instead of POST with mobile keyboard "Go"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mobile

When a user clicks "Go" how can we prevent POST and instead GET `link_to next_challenge_path(challenge: {name: @challenge.name})`?

**_form**

```
<%= f.text_field :name %>
<%= link_to next_challenge_path(challenge: {name: @challenge.name}), id: "challenge-button" do %>
  Save
<% end %>

<script>
  $("#challenge-button").click(function() {
    $(this).attr("href", function() {
      return this.href + $('.form-control').val();
    });
  });
</script>
```

[image]

**logs**

```
2017-02-11T11:27:24.259207+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/challenges" for 110.171.153.192 at 2017-02-11 11:27:24 +0000
2017-02-11T11:27:24.261219+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ChallengesController#create as HTML
2017-02-11T11:27:24.261272+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ozneOQJPp3f91TrRdxUyc02iw7VSBdQ1iMRGhpnDq8KBPHwj4QUTiXrjMTCDy+9XtKatffpexzLKYTV4P8V+lDQ==", "challenge"=>{"name"=>"Test"}}
2017-02-11T11:27:24.272414+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://www.livetochallenge.com/signup
```

I'm using `link_to` because I want the user to fill out more attributes on `next_challenge_path` before being able to submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it how.

Javascript isn't the best solution.

Instead I could use controller `create` action. Add a condition, which says if an attribute is `nil` then redirect_to to `next_challenge_path`

Answer (score 0):

is there a submit button on your page, go button will automatically trigger it when pressed

Look at this link there are two possible solution
1. To disable go button
2. Or to disable form submit action

[How can I prevent the Go button on iPad/iPhone from posting the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614589/how-can-i-prevent-the-go-button-on-ipad-iphone-from-posting-the-form)

Comment: There is no "submit" button on page.

Comment: With the code I provided how would you trigger GET instead of POST?

Comment: is there no other button on the page with action submit ?

Comment: then try to onsubmit="return false; for the form on the page

Comment: I'm still an amateur with javascript, how would I do that?

Comment: :onclick => "return false;" add this to form tag

Comment: Thanks for your insight! I figured out how to do it will just rails :]